# Update all cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a method that I want to run on every cell in my UITableView, which would **update a property in each cell** (and the display would consequently reflect the change). How can I do this?

Comment: `[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "cell" shouldn't really hold any information so you don't really update a cell.

You update the data model (i.e. the array or whatever) that you are using to store data that then gets displayed in the table.

Then when you want to "update the cells" you just update the data model data and then reload the table with...

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: What If I want to update the look and feel of all cells, such as removing a bottom border for all cells except for the selected one?

Comment: well, in that case you add a boolean to your dataModel object which indicates wether border should present or not